# Victron Charge Controller with Amperage limit

Tags: current, resistors, amperage, solar-charge-controller

I'm looking into charge controllers that have features to limit the charge rate of a battery. I've got a small battery bank, and only want to charge at say 10Amps max.

It looks like many of the Victron models have this capability. My question is, what happens to the excess amperage coming from the panels? Is it burned off as heat, or is something in the charge controller physically limiting the amperage coming in from the panel lines?

If its physical, what device/concept would be doing that limiting?

Lastly, there appears to be no limit on the setting. If I limit the charging to 1 AMP, and I've got 20 AMPs coming in, presumably the device has been rated to handle that type of load? (Again worried about heat)

Comment: depends on how the charge controller is designed ... it makes no sense for it to pull extra current, but you never know what the designer was thinking

Comment: @jsotola I'm not so concerned about extra current, more-so in high-current situations (full sun) how the current is limited. (Buck Converters, PWM, etc which all produce heat)

Answer (score 0):

> What happens to the excess amperage coming from the panels?

There isn't any excess amperage. Current in a wire is something like fluid flowing in a pipe, and your battery charger is something like a valve that is automatically controlled to restrict the flow. No matter how much current your solar panel may be *capable* of supplying, the charger will not *allow* the panel to supply more current than what the charger thinks is right for the battery.

Comment: With this in mind, if I had 100 panels producing 800 amps, so long as I set the controller to limit to 10 amps, it could handle it? I'm looking to understand how that "limit" is being done.
If in fact the line between the panels and the controller is only "allowing" 10 amps, how is that restriction being done?

Comment: Your solar array might be _capable_ of supplying 800 amps, but if nothing is hooked up to it, then it won't supply any amps at all. If only that little 10A charger is hooked up to it, then it won't supply any more amps than the charger wants to use.\*

Comment: \*Amps going in to the charger could be significanly _less_ than the amps coming out if the voltage on the input side is significantly greater than the battery voltage. Modern chargers work like _switching power supplies_ which can trade voltage for current and vice versa. So long as the input voltage is within the range that the charger can accept, it will take as much _power_ as it needs from the solar array, and no more.

Comment: Would you know the device used to facilitate that?
I've got a cheap PWM controller that definitely does not abide by that rule. if the sun is out, those panels are sending MAX amps through the door, regardless of what the controller does with it (I.E if the battery is full, those 8 amps turn into heat)

Comment: @2b77bee6-5445-4c77-b1eb-4df3e5, heat where? In the controller itself? Have you actually _measured_ eight amps at the charger's input when the output has shut down? Or, heat in the battery? Have you actually verified that the controller actually does stop charging the battery when it ought to do? Either way, if the controller still is pulling 8A when it says that the battery is fully charged, then something is wrong.